# Enable Nvidia GPU if integrated GPU get stressed

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

I'm using a notebook with both Intel and Nvidia GPUs. I correctly installed nvidia-331 drivers, cuda and bumblebee and I can correctly run `optirun some_application`.
Indeed, while some application is opened with the `optirun` command, the nvidia GPU works correctly

```
sudo lshw -c video | grep driver
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

However, I'm searching for a way to automatically enable GPU while launching VirtualBox machines (expecially those created by Genymotion). More generally, I'm searching for a way to automatically start the GPU if the Intel integrated GPU get stressed. 
Is it possible? What about nvidia-prime?

EDIT: this is what I have installed so far

```
$>dpkg -l | grep cuda
ii  libcuda1-331                                                         331.38-0ubuntu7.1                                   amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
ii  libcudart5.5:amd64                                                   5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
ii  nvidia-cuda-dev                                                      5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development files
ii  nvidia-cuda-doc                                                      5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     all          NVIDIA CUDA and OpenCL documentation
ii  nvidia-cuda-gdb                                                      5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA GDB
ii  nvidia-cuda-toolkit                                                  5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA toolkit
$>dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-331                                                           331.38-0ubuntu7.1                                   amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38
ii  nvidia-331-dev                                                       331.38-0ubuntu7.1                                   amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-331-uvm                                                       331.38-0ubuntu7.1                                   amd64        NVIDIA Unified Memory kernel module
ii  nvidia-cuda-dev                                                      5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development files
ii  nvidia-cuda-doc                                                      5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     all          NVIDIA CUDA and OpenCL documentation
ii  nvidia-cuda-gdb                                                      5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA GDB
ii  nvidia-cuda-toolkit                                                  5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA toolkit
ii  nvidia-libopencl1-331                                                331.38-0ubuntu7.1                                   amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL Driver and ICD Loader library
ii  nvidia-opencl-dev:amd64                                              5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL development files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-331                                                331.38-0ubuntu7.1                                   amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-profiler                                                      5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
ii  nvidia-settings                                                      331.20-0ubuntu8                                     amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-visual-profiler                                               5.5.22-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA Visual Profiler
$>dpkg -l | grep bumblebee
ii  bumblebee                                                            3.2.1-90~trustyppa1                                 amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support
```

EDIT2:
so far the only way to use Nvidia GPU with genymotion (at least for me) is by launching

```
optirun <genymotion-folder>/player --vm-name "X"
```

where X is the name of your virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar to the original request can be found in the nvidia-prime project.
However, after some tests, I decided to get back to optirun. The main reason is that prime keep your nvidia GPU always on, with a lot more power consumption.